# C# Deedle AggregateRowsBy Syntax

Tags: c#, data-manipulation, deedle

I have a dataset like this:

```
Group1  Group2  Value
  A       1     350.6
  A       2     30.5
  B       1     34.1
  B       1     500.2
  C       2     20.7
  C       2     35
```

I would like to aggregate this dataset by Group1 and Group2, and then sum Value:

```
Group1  Group2  Value
  A       1     350.6
  A       2     30.5
  B       1     534.3
  C       2     55.7
```

I know in C# Deedle has a method called "AggregateRowsBy", however its F# syntax doesn't apply to C#. So I have tried the method like this, and it doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Deedle;

namespace testDeedle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          var testdata = Frame.ReadCsv(@"test_data.csv");

          var test2 =testdata.AggregateRowsBy(new string[2] {"Group1","Group2"},
                                            new string[1] {"Value"},
                                            x=>x.NumSum());
          test2.Print();

        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't found enough online resources demonstrating the usage of Deedle in C#. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler isn't able to figure out the type parameters for the `AggregateRowsBy` call, the simplest way to fix it is

```
var test2 = testdata.AggregateRowsBy<double, dynamic>(new []{ "Group1", "Group2" },
                                    new[] { "Value" },
                                    x => x.NumSum());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = testdata.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(x =>new  { Group1 = x.Field<string>("Group1"), Group2 = x.Field<int>("Group2") })
                          .Select(g=> new { Group1 = g.Key.Group1, Group2 = g.Key.Group2, Value = g.Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("Value"))}).ToList();
```

You can do it using linq.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; unfortunately it doesn't convert to list successfully.

Comment: @chl111 it converts if this are the correct types of your columns